# Which version is correct: 出会って or 出会いで?

Tags: て-form

What is the correct version of "It was nice meeting you!":

出会ってよかった。

or

出会いでよかった。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The former is the correct sentence. "It was nice to `verb`" translates to "`te-form` よかった(です)", and 出会いで is not a te-form.

(出会い is a [noun with a fixed meaning](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%87%BA%E4%BC%9A%E3%81%84), and 出会いでよかった would mean something like "Rendezvous was the right choice". It's hard to imagine when to say this.)

Comment: Thank you for confirming. The funny thing, yesterday at a hanami party all native Japanese were trying to convince me that 出会いでよかった was the right expression :)

Comment: @user1602 「出会えてよかった」を聞き間違えたんじゃないでしょうか？

Comment: @user1602 I think it's either that you misheard it or that they were thinking of a weird context. As I said, 出会いで良かった is not ungrammatical (at least technically speaking, it means something much less useful than "It was nice meeting you".)

Comment: Misheard is out of the question. I had an argument with them insisting that 出会ってよかった。was the correct way saying that, and they were saying that 出会いでよかった。:) Probably we all had too much to drink :)